# Autofill spreadsheet data from Excel

Tags: ms-access, excel

So I've got an Excel template I send to clients and they fill in one cell with a type of resource they need, and I check an Access database for available resources to find what we have and fill out things accordingly. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

The client wants some rental cars from the ones that I have. They copy the rows and add SUV/Sedan/Van/Truck into column B. Say they have three requests for SUVs and five requests for Sedans. How could I import data like make, model, and year, based on these entries? I want to be able to query which vehicles have the attribute they want and fill in which ones are available, preferably sorted newest to oldest, with blank entries if I don't have anything available.